# findByIdAndRemove giving casterror?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
        const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
        console.log(checkedItemId);
        Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("successfull");
                res.redirect("/");
            }
            else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
```

> Getting Error=> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
> "60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12bd " (type string) at path "_id" for model
> "Item"
> at model.Query.exec
>
> ```
>  stringValue: '"60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12bd "',
>   kind: 'ObjectId',
>   value: '60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12bd ',
>   path: '_id',
>   reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
>       at new ObjectID
> ```

Comment: Can you try showing a screenshot or copy, paste and format the error stack trace.

Comment: @web_walkerX made some changes hope it helps

Comment: It looks like your stringValue has embedded double quotes and a space at the end. It could be that you need to clean up your inputs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CastError is a mongoDB database error. It is not from mongoose itself, so it can become somewhat difficult to detect and handle.

There are a number of reasons that it could occur:
Normal database id (just an example): 60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12bd

1. wrong number of characters for the _id
   ex: 60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12b  <-- (missing the d)
2. Misplaced letters/numbers in the _id
   ex: 60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12b2 <-- (2 replacing the d)

You typically want to handle it just like any other bad request.
What I would do, is I send the user this:

```
    app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
        const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

        console.log(checkedItemId);
        Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function (err) {
            if(err) {
               res.status(400).json({
                  status: "fail",
                  message: `Invalid ${err.path}: ${err.value}.`,
                  // example of message: Invalid _id: 60e0e8cb00ae7846549e12b
               });
            }

            // If no error
            res.status(200).json({..});
        });
    });
```

**Edit:** Mongoose errors typically give you the nice errors that you are used to seeing, but mongoDB errors are usually a bit more messy

Answer (score 0):

check the id is valid or not before using it :-

```js
const { isValidObjectId } = require('mongoose')

 app.post("/delete",async function (req, res) {
   const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

   if (!isValidObjectId(checkedItemId)) {
      return res.status(404).send("Not found")
   }
        
   await Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId)

   res.redirect("/")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line:-

```
    const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox.toString().trim();
```

Rest will work fine.

Comment: I compleled that bootcamp.